# What is $ d B_t \sqrt{d t} $, where $B_t$ is the Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices

Consider the time-evolution operator $U(dt) = \exp(-id tJH_0 - i d B_t V)$ where $H_0$ and $V$ are some Hamiltonians, and $J$ is some coupling. $B_t$ is the Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}$ with $B_0 = 0$. From physically motivated conditions, the coupling must be rescaled as $J = \sqrt{\gamma /dt}$, and after replacing this in $U(dt)$, I end up with terms of the form

$$ U(d t) = I - i\sqrt{\gamma dt}H_0 - id B_t V - \frac{1}{2}[\gamma dt H_0^2 + d t V^2 + dB_t \sqrt{dt} (VH_0 + H_0V)],$$

where I have used the usual rules $d t^2 = 0, d B_t^2 = dt,$ etc. Can I take $dB_t\sqrt{d t} = 0$? I have searched for products of that form, but I have not found any.

Comment: Seems that physics is almost rigorous if and only if they get the units right. Where is that from? To figure out what $dB_t\sqrt{dt}$ is I would pretend that in the $JH_0$ term there is effectively a $dB_t$ as well (instead of $\sqrt{dt}$). Then you should get the more familiar $dB_t^2=dt$.

Comment: @KurtG. No. That is not allowed in my problem. And to answer your question: the issue comes from the measurement operators associated with the Hamiltonian $H(t) = JH_0 + V\xi(t)$, where we (in)formally take $d B_t = \xi(t)d t$.